# Sort integer array based on custom comparator

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

This is something simple but I'm obviously missing something....

I have a 2D array that contains integer representations of Color values that have been calculated from a BufferedImage object.  I also have a method to calculate the brightness value based on the integer values.

I want to sort rows based on the brightness value.  However, I'm getting

```
sort(java.lang.Integer[], Comparator<? super Integer>) in Arrays cannot be applied
to (int[], IntComparator)
```

My comparator method:

```
private class IntComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{
  @Override
  public int compare(Integer x, Integer y){
    return (PhotoUtils.getBrightnessValue(x) <= PhotoUtils.getBrightnessValue(y)) ? x : y;
  }
}
```

Inside my sortRow method, I have

```
public void sortRow(int row) {
  Arrays.sort(this.buffer[row], new IntComparator());
}
```

What is the issue here?  After all, I'm just calculating two integer values based on the input and returning either < 0 or > 0.

Comment: You're conflating int[] and Integer[].  Note that you can autobox/auto-unbox from int to Integer and vice versa, but not from Integer[] to int[] and neither vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to declare the `buffer` attribute as an `Integer[]`, because you defined the comparator for the `Integer` type, not for the `int` type - and the `sort()` method that receives a `Comparator` will only work for arrays of object types, not for arrays of primitive types such as `int`.

Be aware that an `int[]` can not be automatically converted to `Integer[]`, it might be necessary to explicitly create a new `Integer[]` and copy the `int[]` elements into it:

```
int[] myIntArray = ...;
Integer[] myIntegerArray = new Integer[myIntArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < myIntArray.length; i++)
    myIntegerArray[i] = myIntArray[i]; // autoboxing takes care of conversion
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator)` is a generic method where both the first and second parameters use the type variable. Since primitives can't be used as generic type arguments, ex. `Comparator<int>`, you cannot pass an `int[]` as the first argument.

You will need to pass an `Integer[]`.